# UPDATING MYSQL record error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am working on a script to update a record. The script is fine in my view and I am also getting a success message but the record is not being updated in the database. Please help me sort this out.

Here is my Form page.

```
<!-- Inquiry Table Stars here -->

<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql = "Select * From inquiry WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


?>

<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$name = $row['cname'];;
$email = $row['email'];;
$phone = $row['phone'];;
$sdate = $row['sdate'];;
$edate = $row['edate'];;
$fdate = $row['fdate'];;

?>




<!-- Code Begins -->
<center>
<div class="vpb_main_wrapper">

<br clear="all">
<form method="post" action="edit_ac.php">
<h2 align="left" style="margin-top:0px;">Edit Operator</h2><br />

<div align="left" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px; margin-bottom:10px;">Edit operator Details.</div><br />

<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left"> Full Name:</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left"><input type="text" name="cname" id="cname" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs" required>
</div><br clear="all"><br clear="all">

<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left"> Email:</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs" required>
</div><br clear="all"><br clear="all">


<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left">Mobile:</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left"><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" required class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs">
</div><br clear="all"><br clear="all">


<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left">Start Date:</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left"><input type="text" name="sdate" id="sdate" value="<?php echo $sdate; ?>" required class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs">
</div><br clear="all"><br clear="all">


<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left">End Date:</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left"><input type="text" name="edate" id="edate" value="<?php echo $edate; ?>" required class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs">
</div><br clear="all"><br clear="all">


<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left">Date of Journey:</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left"><input type="text" name="fdate" id="fdate" value="<?php echo $fdate; ?>" class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs" required>
</div><br clear="all"><br clear="all">

<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">

<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 100px" class="vpb_general_button">

</div>

</form>
<br clear="all"><br clear="all">

</div><?php } ?>
</center>
<!-- Code Ends -->


<!-- Inquiry Table Ends here -->
```

And Here is my edit_ac.php

```
  <?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="pro1"; // Database name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$name = $_POST['cname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$sdate = $_POST['sdate'];
$edate = $_POST['edate'];
$fdate = $_POST['fdate'];

// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE inquiry SET 
      cname = '$name', 
      email = '$email',
      phone = '$phone', 
      sdate = '$sdate', 
      edate = '$edate', 
      fdate = '$fdate'  
      WHERE id='$id'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated.
if($result){
echo "Successfull";

}

else {
echo "Error";
}

?>
```

It is showing "0 record updated successfully". So its not updated in the database. Whats the problem please help.

Comment: None of the values, like `$id`, is set in the latter script. You just assume it is set, but they are not.

Comment: i have done $_POST also but its not working

Comment: see the post again i have edited edit_ac.php page... still not working..

Comment: You really should look at prepared statements, or at the very least using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) as your code is ridiculously vulnerable

Comment: THIS UPDATE CODE I took from http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql-cate.php?category=update
see if this helps solve the problem plz help me

Comment: before fixing the code. Try checking the submitting value if they are valid. echo $_POST['cname']; echo $_POST['email']; .....

Comment: also don't forget to check your id. echo it out as well, to see if there is such id number in your database table

Comment: By the way you didn't declare $id variable in your edit_acc.php it has no value that's why the query doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare the $id variable. I added this line: $id = $_POST['id'];

Anyway, mysql functions are deprecated: use mysqli instead.

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="pro1"; // Database name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['cname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$sdate = $_POST['sdate'];
$edate = $_POST['edate'];
$fdate = $_POST['fdate'];

// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE inquiry SET 
  cname = '$name', 
  email = '$email',
  phone = '$phone', 
  sdate = '$sdate', 
  edate = '$edate', 
  fdate = '$fdate'  
    WHERE id='$id'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated.
if($result){
echo "Successfull";

}

else {
echo "Error";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I think, is that you're in both cases not passing `$id` variable to the query correctly:

You do:

```
WHERE id='$id'"
```

You should:

```
WHERE id=" . $id .""
```

**EDIT 1:** Try checking by printing `$id` variable, if you really have it set at all:

```
var_dump($id);
```

**EDIT 2:**

Do the rest with other variables:

```
$sql = "UPDATE 
          inquiry
        SET 
          cname = " . $name . ", 
          email = " . $email . ",
          phone = " . $phone . ", 
          sdate = " . $sdate . ", 
          edate = " . $edate . ", 
          fdate = " . $fdate . "  
        WHERE 
          id=" . $id . "";
```

Also try printing and checking if you really get `$name, $email, $phone` and etc..

Comment: its showing an error... before it was showing a successful msg (though not updated in the database) but now after applying this its not even showing the success msg. its resulting in an error.

Comment: @SanjeevSarkar It should not be showing an error if you replace `id='$id'` with `id=" . $id ."`. Read _Edit 1_.

Comment: i echoed it and i can get that value... but the updation is not working.

Comment: THIS UPDATE CODE I took from http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql-cate.php?category=update
see if this helps solve the problem plz help me

Answer (score -3):

Store your id value in Session so you can use it on different page as well. Here the edit file doesn't have the ID.

Hope it helps.

Comment: THIS UPDATE CODE I took from http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql-cate.php?category=update
it used to work before for me always but now its not working.

Comment: Don't know about your past exp but what I can see here is the edit query not getting the ID value. I would suggest try my solution,in case you are unaware of SESSION concept let me know i can explain,but to downvote is just not the right thing to do.